# Refer to temporary table in Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

There is a list *list* in memory of 50,000 Product IDs. I would like to get all these Products from the DB. Using `dbContext.Products.Where(p => list.contains(p.ID))` generates a giant IN in the SQL - `WHERE ID IN (2134,1324543,5675,32451,45735...)`, and it takes forever. This is partly because it takes time for SQL Server to parse such a large string, and also the execution plan is bad. (I know this from trying to use a temporary table instead).

So I used SQLBulkCopy to insert the IDs to a temporary table, and then ran

```
dbContext.Set<Product>().SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM #tmp))"
```

This gave good performance. However, now I need the products, with their suppliers (multiple for every product). Using a custom SQL command there is no way to get back a complex object that I know of. So how can I get the products with their suppliers, using the temporary table?

(If I can somehow refer to the temporary table in LINQ, then it would be OK - I could just do `dbContext.Products.Where(p => dbContext.TempTable.Any(t => t.ID==p.ID))`. If I could refer to it in a UDF that would also be good - but you can't. I cannot use a real table, since concurrent users would leave it in an inconsistent state.)

Thanks

Comment: You could use a real table that has a column with the `userid` in it

Comment: Do you mean ProductID? I already mentioned that possibility at the end.

Comment: If you include the user id or some other distinguishing field in your filter table (TempTable) then you won't get a problem with concurrent users.

Comment: @qujck That's a good idea - I don't have user IDs, but could use a GUID instead. I actually started trying to use TransactionScope, but this is a better- I would mark it as Answer.

Comment: @StephenByrne I'm importing 50,000 sales from a file into a grid - each row = one sale. The grid needs access to all the products that were sold, for various reasons, such as product limitations, warnings etc.. This is not really my scenario, but I think is functionally equivalent. If needed, I'll set the log to NORECOVERY. Please let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: Does this Join syntax help you? Your problem looks very similar....but perhaps with different versions of EF...http://stackoverflow.com/a/19448221/150342

Comment: @wezten ok so is it some kind of bulk import tool or something - I presume that you can't page the data in the client application?

Comment: @Colin Not really - that's not using temporary tables

Comment: @StephenByrne Not sure I understand - the sales are read from a file. The products cannot be cached because there are too many.

Comment: @wezten I'm trying to get a sense if there is human interaction with the data after it's loaded, or if this is an automated solution and you are trying to do it with temp tables for performance reasons, etc? If its being loaded into an on-screen gird then why not page the data i.e only load a subset of the related entities at a time or is there some reason why all 50K lines must have the related entities loaded. Or could you for example not load all 50k records and select in-memory the distinct list of supplier codes and then load these supplier entities in one go, etc.

Comment: @StephenByrne It needs all the records at the beginning, because it needs show the sales with warnings first, and it needs the Product record to create the warnings. "Or could you for example not load all 50k records" - do you mean with a temp table and SqlBulkCopy? And then all over again for the suppliers? That's a lot of code - and also what if I have a third level (which I actually do)?

Comment: @wezten what I meant was something different but tbh as you're happy enough with the temp table route, I don't want to turn this into a long drawn-out comment affair :)....if you run into performance issues with your chosen approach post back here and we can go into more detail then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you extend the filter table (`TempTable` in the code above) to store something like a `UserId` or `SessionId` as well as `ProductID's`:

- this will give you all the performance you're after
- it will work for concurrent users

If this filter table is changing a lot then consider updating it in a separate transaction (i.e. a different instance of `dbContext`) to avoid holding a write lock on this table for longer than necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I was curious to explore the sql generated using `Join` syntax rather than `Contains`. Here is the code for my test:

```
IQueryable<Product> queryable = Uow.ProductRepository.All;
List<int> inMemKeys = new int[] { 2134, 1324543, 5675, 32451, 45735 }.ToList();
string sql1 = queryable.Where(p => inMemKeys.Contains(p.ID)).ToString();

string sql2 = queryable.Join(inMemKeys, t => t.ID, pk => pk, (t, pk) => t).ToString();
```

This is the sql generated using Contains (sql1)

```
SELECT
    [extent1].[id] AS [id],...etc
FROM [dbo].[products] AS [extent1]
WHERE ([extent1].[id] IN (2134, 1324543, 5675, 32451, 45735))
```

This is the sql generated using Join:

```
SELECT
    [extent1].[id] AS [id],...etc
FROM [dbo].[products] AS [extent1]
    INNER JOIN (SELECT
        [unionall3].[c1] AS [c1]
    FROM (SELECT
        [unionall2].[c1] AS [c1]
    FROM (SELECT
        [unionall1].[c1] AS [c1]
    FROM (SELECT
        2134 AS [c1]
    FROM (SELECT
        1 AS x) AS [singlerowtable1] UNION ALL SELECT
        1324543 AS [c1]
    FROM (SELECT
        1 AS x) AS [singlerowtable2]) AS [unionall1] UNION ALL SELECT
        5675 AS [c1]
    FROM (SELECT
        1 AS x) AS [singlerowtable3]) AS [unionall2] UNION ALL SELECT
        32451 AS [c1]
    FROM (SELECT
        1 AS x) AS [singlerowtable4]) AS [unionall3] UNION ALL SELECT
        45735 AS [c1]
    FROM (SELECT
        1 AS x) AS [singlerowtable5]) AS [unionall4]
        ON [extent1].[id] = [unionall4].[c1]
```

So the sql creates a big select statement using union all to create the equivalent of your temporary table, then it joins to that table. The sql is more verbose, but it may well be efficient - I'm afraid I'm not qualified to say.

While it doesn't answer the question as set out in the heading, it does show a way to avoid the giant `IN` . OK.... now it's a giant `UNION ALL`.... anyways...I hope that this contribution is useful to some