# Optimizing LINQ queries - How can I improve the execution time?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm wondering if there is a good way to optimize my LINQ queries. I am retrieving data from a database using a LINQ query similar to the following:

```
// PKs is a list of integers   
var import = context.table.Where(x => PKs.Contains(x.PrimaryKey)).AsEnumerable();
```

I assumed (incorrectly) that this would result in a SQL call like the following:

```
SELECT * from table where PrimaryKey in (PK[1], PK[2], ...)
```

i.e 1 database hit. Using [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) to inspect the SQL calls I saw that the LINQ query was translated into many separate SQL calls, e.g:

```
SELECT * from table where PrimaryKey=PK[1]
SELECT * from table where PrimaryKey=PK[2]
...
```

The individual queries were being executed very quickly, but as my list of integers was large (in the thousands), the  offset due to overheads was resulting in the query taking around 25 seconds to run.

I decided to strip out the time-consuming LINQ queries with database calls and import the data via a stored procedure call:

```
var import = this.p_import(parameter).ToList();
```

This dramatically improved the response time, as there was only one database call, from about 25 seconds to under 1 second.

This solved my problem, but the whole reason I was using LINQ was to avoid using stored procedures. Is there a better way I could optimize my LINQ queries?

Comment: You can use `context.table.Where(x => x.PrimaryKey==PK[1] || x.PrimaryKey==PK[2]).AsEnumerable();`

Comment: It is wrong to pass thousands of objects as a command parameter of a qurery. You should keep them in a separate table, index the columns and make effective joins.

Comment: Where do the contents of PK come from?

Comment: Are you using Linq2Sql or Linq2Entities. Which version of EF?

Comment: EF 4, Linq2Entities. Thanks spender I am going to mark your answer as correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change to a join, things should go a lot more smoothly.

```
context.table.Join(PKs,t => t.PrimaryKey, pk => pk, (t, pk) => t).AsEnumerable()
```

Linq2Sql does not support joining entities to POCO lists, but just tested with EF and all is good.

With Linq2Sql, you're stuck with `Contains`, in which case, I'd probably just go for a stored procedure with table-value parameters.

Answer (score 0):

EF 4should support IN query translation. I've never had issues with Contains in EF however it seems that earlier versions do not correctly support it.

[You can find more details and a possible solution here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx)